# Java, String.matches difference

Tags: java, regex

`String.matches` gives different result (I think it has good reason, but I don't know why).

See my example below:

**Complex program:**

```
...
line.matches(pattern) -> false
...
```

**Simple program:**

```
String line = "blabla"; //copy pasted during debug of Complex program
String pattern = "bl.*"; //copy pasted during debug of Complex program

line.matches(pattern) -> true
```

**Q:** How can I find out what makes the match wrong in the Complex program?

Comment: Debugger: "Heeeey!".

Comment: Simple `println()` would also do!

Comment: @RaviThapliyal `println` **MUST DIE**. Learn how to use **logging**!

Comment: @user2013619: you have to examine the values of `line` and `pattern` when it returns `false`. There are many (easy) ways of doing so, but we can't do it for you.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse Yeah, I agree. But, the OP feels his code is already complex! :)

Comment: @RaviThapliyal proper logging doesn't increase code complexity. Adding and *removing* `System.out` to debug is *much* more work, because they can't be easily toggled on and off as needed!

Comment: @Anony-Mousse Yes, I completely agree with you. I was just of the opinion that even a simple `println()` in OP's supposedly complex program could have given him a better insight into why it isn't matching the pattern. I'm not proposing `println()` over logging. You just have read a tad more into my one-liner.

Answer (score 11):

It is very probably that you are yet another programmer who fell trap to how Java's `.matches()` operates -- and which lead many people to consider that method's name a misnomer.

Read this, imprint this into your head using red iron:

**Java's `.matches()` method behaves as if the regex given as an argument were surrounded by the beginning-of-input `^` and end-of-input `$` anchors. As a result, it tries and matches the regex on the whole input.**

This is unlike the definition of "regex matching" adopted by the vast majority of programming languages using regexes (and which yours truly agrees with), where a regex can match **anywhere** in the input. As you will see from the many comments below, others do not agree.

That is:

```
"foobar".matches("foobar") == true
"foobar and something else".matches("foobar") == false
```

**Real** regex matching in Java is done using `.find()`; and `String` doesn't have it. You have to use a `Pattern` and a `Matcher`:

```
final Pattern p = Pattern.compile("foobar");
final Matcher m = p.matcher("foobar and something else");
m.find(); // true!
m.matches(); // false!
```

I.e. `matches()` will actually use the pattern `"^foobar$"`.

Comment: I've just looked at the sources, and what you say about the `.matches()` method is not true. Can you link any sources?

Comment: Sorry but it _is_ true. Just try it!

Comment: You should say `matches()` does not do a sub-string match instead of saying it doesn't do a regex match. It would be misleading to newbies.

Comment: @RaviThapliyal this is the sad truth: `.matches()` does not do what is called regex matching; a regex matches text anywhere in its input, `.matches()` doesn't

Comment: @jlordo it does not explicitly add the anchors, but it does try to match the whole string via the `ENDANCHOR` flag.

Comment: I don't consider `matches()` misnamed, because it checks whether `this` String `matches` the given regex. You are confusing _pattern finding_ and _pattern matching_. Modify your example to `"foobar and something else".matches("foobar.*")` and the string `matches` the given regex.

Comment: @jlordo I do consider it misnamed because of the definition of "regex matching"; take any other language manual on regexes and you'll see what I mean. If I want to match `foobar` and only `foobar`, I use `"^foobar$"`, not `"foobar"`

Comment: @assylias: exactly. Just as documented, the `matches()` method checks whether the complete string matches the given regex. It doesn't say if the regex can be found as a substring.

Comment: @RaviThapliyal fge is right. Java **is** nonstandard here, as in the `find` method does what is commonly called "*matching*" a regular expression, while the `match` method does an anchored exact match (with implicit `^` and `$`)

Comment: @fge Yes, matches does not match text anywhere because of the anchors but it still honours the regex syntax and hence it's wrong to say it doesn't do regex. It just tries to *match the regex* on the complete input.

Comment: According to the section _Basic Concepts_ in [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) pattern consumes the complete input string when trying to determine if it **matches** or not.

Comment: @jlordo or when Wikipedia gets it only partially right! "I am Hændel, I tell you" is also matched by "Hændel".

Comment: I guess we'll have to agree to disagree on this one. You're trying to say, that `"abc".matches("b")` _should_ be `true`, but `abc` simply does not `match` the pattern `b`. The pattern `b` can be found in `abc`, but it does not match the complete expression `abc`. So the `find` method is there to `find` a pattern in a string, and the `matches` method is there to check whether an expression `matches` a pattern.

Comment: Yes indeed. For me, `"b"` matches `"b"` in `"abc"`!

Comment: So it does for me. And for **perl**, and **sed** and **awk** and **libpcre**.
It does *not* match the pattern `^b$`, though, which is anchored.

Comment: I'm in complete agreement with jlordo. `matches()` isn't a misnomer. Only a 100% match (and not a partial one) should truly be called as *a match*.

Comment: It's interesting that this seems to be a point where formal language theory and programming diverge - in the formal world we would use the word match to describe the case where the full string matches the expression, not the substring case. Although I think many languages have made the alternative more common.

Comment: @RaviThapliyal 90+% of languages using regexes disagree with you... I know of two languages only who agree: Java and Python. Even .NET languages `.Match()` "b" in "abc".

Comment: Even the examples on above wikipedia page include `^` and `$` to anchor the match... and the POSIX examples also require `$` to match at the end of line only...

Comment: @fge Then, I'm glad that Java wasn't influenced by them. I think it could be a matter of taste here. I feel the name is more natural because of what the word "matches" itself means and I can also understand why its behaviour would feel incorrect to anyone well versed with the languages mentioned above.

Comment: Ohwell, edited the answer to reflect the fact that there are people who don't agree with 35+ years of regex practice ;)

Comment: +1 for the disclaimer then :)

Comment: +1 for making the point, @fge