# String.matches fails every test?

Tags: java, regex, string

I have an really odd behaviour of String.matches:

```
requestString.matches(".*")
    (boolean) false
```

while requestString is something like

> "HTTP/1.1 200 OK - OK 
>   [...]
>   Content-Type: text/xml; Charset=iso-8859-1
>   Content-Length: 1545"
>  + more...

Of cause, I want to test against "HTTP/\\d\\.\\d
but obviously this fails eighter:
requestString.matches("HTTP/\\d\\.\\d")

The String in requestString comes in via Socket connection and is send in iso-8859-1 encoding. Here is the code,

```
StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
int ch;
while ( ! timeoutExceeded() && (ch = reader.read()) != -1) {
    result.append((char)ch);
}
String requestString = result.toString()
```

The code is running on android sdk.
What am I missing? Is the encoding the problem?

Solution:
thanks to the hints I tried the DotAll flag (again!) and it works:

```
requestString.matches("(?s).*HTTP/\\d\\.\\d.*")
```

Comment: Beware that `.matches()` tries and applies the regex to the _whole input_! That's a huge trap...

Comment: Please don't post the answer in the question.  Answers should be posted as answers, and then select one as your accepted answer.  This way we know your question is fulfilled.

Comment: I know, @shyam was so fast, stackoverflow didn't accept me to accept his answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`matches` must match the entire string and since you are trying to match a multi-line string your pattern is not matching the complete string

eg.

```
System.out.println("HTTP/1.1 200 OK - OK".matches(".*")); //true
System.out.println("HTTP/1.1 200 OK - OK\nContent-Type: text/xml".matches(".*")); // false
```

Comment: This did it:
requestString.matches("(?s).*HTTP/\\d\\.\\d.*")

Answer (score 2):

First, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17044168/java-string-matches-difference/17044276#17044276).

Second, by default, the dot does **not** match newlines. As your input is multiline, this means the regex cannot match.

You have to use a `Pattern` and compile with `Pattern.DOTALL`:

```
final Pattern p = Pattern.compile(".*", Pattern.DOTALL);
p.matcher(anything).matches(); // always returns true
```

Illustration:

```
public static void main(final String... args)
{
    final String input = "a\nb";
    System.out.println(input.matches(".*"));
    System.out.println(Pattern.compile(".*", Pattern.DOTALL)
        .matcher(input).matches());
}
```

Result:

```
false
true
```